# Refresh tkinter GUI after scanning three barcodes and compare strings

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and very new to GUI tkinter. I am working on a project for work that is a simple task, but I wanted to try to make it work using a GUI. The task is to scan three barcodes, parse the last nine digits of the barcodes, and compare. If they all match, then display "pass"; if they don't display, "fail". I have written the code using the basic command line and I was able to get everything to work. Now I am trying to implement that code with a graphical user interface, which is where I am struggling.

The issue I am running into is knowing how or what to update/refresh. My logic works as long as I have a string entered in the ENTRY text box before the code is executed. If the strings are different, it fails; if they are the same or empty, it passes.

I wanted to be able to scan three serial numbers and have the bottom frame update pass or fail and then scan a different set of serial numbers and get another result. See my code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

```
from tkinter import *


# FUNCTION THAT ALLOWS THE CURSOR TO MOVE TO THE NEXT ENTRY TEXT BOX AUTOMATICALLY.
def go_to_next_entry(event, entry_list, this_index):
next_index = (this_index + 1) % len(entry_list)
entry_list[next_index].focus_set()


# FUNCTION THAT DETERMINES IF THE THREE SERIAL NUMBERS ARE THE SAME OR DIFFERENT.
# DISPLAYS PASS OR FAIL BASED ON RESULT OF CONDITION.
def get_results():

# DECLARING AND INITIALISING VARIABLES THAT ARE EQUAL TO INPUT FROM ENTRY TEXT BOXES.
scan_one = scan_one_entry.get()
scan_two = scan_two_entry.get()
scan_three = scan_three_entry.get()

# PARSING THE LAST NINE DIGITS OF THE ENTERED STRING.
parsed_scan_one = scan_one[-9:]
parsed_scan_two = scan_two[-9:]
parsed_scan_three = scan_three[-9:]

# IF-ELSE CONDITION THAT DISPLAYS PASS IF THREE SERIAL NUMBERS ARE THE SAME AND FAIL IF THEY 
ARE NOT THE SAME.
if parsed_scan_one == parsed_scan_two and parsed_scan_two == parsed_scan_three and 
parsed_scan_three == parsed_scan_one:

    # DELETING DATA THAT IS STORED IN ENTRY TEXT BOXES.
    scan_one_entry.delete(0, END)
    scan_two_entry.delete(0, END)
    scan_three_entry.delete(0, END)

    # PLACING THE PASS BOTTOM FRAME IF CONDITION IS MET.
    pass_bottom_frame.grid(row=1, sticky="ns, ew")

    # CREATING PASS BOTTOM FRAME WIDGETS OF IF CONDITION IS MET.
    pass_label = Label(pass_bottom_frame,
                       text='PASSED SCAN CHECK!',
                       font=('Helvetica', 100),
                       justify="center")

    # PICKING BACKGROUND COLOR AND FONT COLOR OF LABEL WIDGET
    pass_label.config(bg="#63d464", fg="#000000")

    # PLACING THE PASS BOTTOM FRAME WIDGET IF CONDITION IS MET
    pass_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

else:

    # DELETING DATA THAT IS STORED IN ENTRY TEXT BOXES.
    scan_one_entry.delete(0, END)
    scan_two_entry.delete(0, END)
    scan_three_entry.delete(0, END)

    # PLACING THE FAILED BOTTOM FRAME.
    fail_bottom_frame.grid(row=1, sticky="ns, ew")

    # CREATING PASS BOTTOM FRAME WIDGETS.
    fail_label = Label(fail_bottom_frame,
                       text='FAILED SCAN CHECK!',
                       font=('Helvetica', 100),
                       justify="center")

    # PICKING BACKGROUND COLOR AND FONT COLOR OF LABEL WIDGET.
    fail_label.config(bg="#f51023", fg="#000000")

    # PLACING THE FAILED BOTTOM FRAME WIDGET.
    fail_label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")

# CREATING MAIN WINDOW
main_window = Tk()
main_window.title('Serial Number Barcode Scan Check')
main_window.state("zoomed")

# CREATING THE MAIN FRAMES THAT WILL BE PLACED IN MAIN WINDOW
top_frame = Frame(main_window, width=1800, height=500)
pass_bottom_frame = Frame(main_window, bg="#63d464",  width=1800, height=500)
fail_bottom_frame = Frame(main_window, bg="#f51023",  width=1800, height=500)

# LAYOUT MAIN TOP FRAME
main_window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_window .grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# PLACING TOP FRAME
top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ns, ew")

# CREATING TOP FRAME WIDGETS
# TOP THREE ARE LABELS AND THE LAST THREE ARE ENTRY BOXES
scan_one_label = Label(top_frame,
                       text='ENTER SCAN ONE: ',
                       font=('Helvetica', 40))
scan_two_label = Label(top_frame,
                       text='ENTER SCAN TWO: ',
                       font=('Helvetica', 40))
scan_three_label = Label(top_frame,
                         text='ENTER SCAN THREE: ',
                         font=('Helvetica', 40))
scan_one_entry = Entry(top_frame, font="Helvetica 20", justify="center", border=5)
scan_two_entry = Entry(top_frame, font="Helvetica 20", justify="center", border=5)
scan_three_entry = Entry(top_frame, font="Helvetica 20", justify="center", border=5)

# PLACING THE TOP FRAME WIDGETS INTO THE TOP FRAME
scan_one_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
scan_two_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
scan_three_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
scan_one_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=100, ipady=8)
scan_two_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=100, ipady=8)
scan_three_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=100, ipady=8)

# CODE USED TO MOVE TO EACH ENTRY TEXT BOX AUTOMATICALLY
entries = [child for child in top_frame.winfo_children() if isinstance(child, Entry)]
for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e, index=index: go_to_next_entry(e, entries, index))

# CALLING THE FUNCTION GET RESULTS
get_results()

# MAIN LOOP
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to call `get_results()` after clicking a button or pressing a hotkey instead.  Also there is indentation issue in your code.

Comment: Also you need to check whether the three entries have content inside them.

Comment: Hello acw1668,

I want to start off by saying thank you for the advice. Is there a way to do that without having a button? I want to try to have it hands free or only controlled with the scanner. I did not know if there was a way to automatically update the whole window or not. I was thinking maybe I would have to destroy it and create a new instance but I am not sure if the new instance of the window would be able to get the strings that were entered. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that `go_to_next_entry()` will be triggered by the input of barcode scanner, right? If yes, you can call `get_results()` inside `go_to_next_entry()` if certain conditions are fulfilled, for example all entries have content.

Comment: acw1668 I wanted to say thanks for the recommendations. Because of you I was able to finish this project. Its been up and running for awhile but I forgot to get on and make sure to say thank you. One issue I was having was that I was not calling the get_results function once I have three strings like you mentioned. Also once I got it to print pass or fail I needed to create another function that deletes each instance of those widgets so I can have a new widget appear once the condition is met. Hope this helps if anyone else runs into this issue!